# Why can't I place a UIActivityIndicatorView on a UITableView by using Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone

I can place a UIActivityIndicatorView on a UIWindow or a UIView by using Interface Builder like as follows.
[image]
<sub>(source: [hatena.ne.jp](http://img.f.hatena.ne.jp/images/fotolife/t/tomute/20100207/20100207004841.png))</sub>

But I can't place a UIActivityIndicatorView on a UITableView by using Interface Builder.
What's the reason? Are there any ways?
I can place it on a UITableView programmatically.
[image]
<sub>(source: [hatena.ne.jp](http://img.f.hatena.ne.jp/images/fotolife/t/tomute/20100207/20100207005325.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `UITableView` and the `UIActivityIndicatorView` both subviews of a parent `UIView`. You can then place the indicator view atop the table view.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, I already knew I can do that when I make the UITableView a subview of UIView. In fact, UITableView is a subclass of UIView, so why I can't make the UIActivityIndicatorView a subview of the UITableView via Interface Builder?

Comment: You could programmatically insert the activity indicator into the table view's superview, but I'm not sure how you would do this with IB. The standard way for solving this is to make both views into child subviews of a parent view. If you think it is a bug, you might file a report at http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: You are right. I always programmatically insert the indicator. To add a parent UIView is another way to solve this issue, but I personally don't like to add a meaningless UIView just for using the indicator.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because UITableView expects to be in charge of all of every one of its subviews for layout purposes.  IB doesn't let you put subviews in a UITableView because while it is technically *possible* it is not *supported*.

In any case, the activity indicator would scroll up and down with the table, so even if you add it at the right place if the table is scrolled down, you could scroll it off the screen if you're not careful about deactivating user interaction while the indicator is showing.

When I need to show a generic activity indicator on the screen over everything, I use my own version of the UIProgressHUD.  The UIProgressHUD is a private internal class, so I don't use that, I just made my own that does the same thing.  It makes a view with a black background at 50% opacity and rounded corners, and I add a progress indicator and optionally a label to it, then I just add that view to the main window.  Thus, no need for another UIView to encapsulate both, and you're not putting it in the table, which isn't supported (unless you put it within a cell within the table view).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, in fact, if I programmatically add an activity indicator to a UITableVIew as a sub view, it's totally fine. (e.g. [self.tableView addSubview:indicator];). The activity indicator doesn't scroll up and down with the table.